# 'EXPO_USE_DEV_SERVER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?

Tags: react-native, expo

'EXPO_USE_DEV_SERVER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. How use this command in windows command prompt ?

Comment: That doesn’t look like a command, but rather an environment variable.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to run your app. Could you try to run `expo start` at the root of your project?

Comment: it is an environment variable, you should investigate how to set that in windows

Comment: expo start works.! 'EXPO_USE_DEV_SERVER = true expo start ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, I want this command to work on cmd prompt have an idea how it works?